# Why does FindMaximum with Newton's method complain it can't find a sufficient decrease in function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

Firstly, this seems like (from ContourPlot) a fairly straightforward maximization problem, why is FindMaximum with Newton's method having problems?

Secondly, how can I get rid of the warnings?

Thirdly, if I can't get rid of these warnings, how can I tell if the warning is meaningful, ie, maximization failed?

For instance, in the code below, FindMaximum with Newton's method gives a warning, whereas the PrincipalAxis method doesn't

```
o = 1/5 Log[E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]))/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   3/10 Log[E^(h/Sqrt[3])/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/5 Log[E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/10 Log[E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/10 Log[E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/10 Log[E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))];
(* -1 makes more contours towards maximum *)

contourFunc[n_, p_] := Function[{min, max},
   range = max - min;
   Table[Exp[p (x - 1)] x range + min, {x, 0, 1, 1/n}]
   ];
cf = contourFunc[10, -1];
ContourPlot @@ {o, {j, -1, 1}, {h, -1, 1}, Contours -> cf}

FindMaximum @@ {o, {{j, 0}, {h, 0}}, Method -> "Newton"}
FindMaximum @@ {o, {{j, 0}, {h, 0}}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"}
```

Note, I thought that maybe gradient being 0 in direction of one of the components was the problem, but if I perturb the initial point I still get the same warning, here's an example

```
o = 1/5 Log[E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]))/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/5 Log[E^(h/Sqrt[3])/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/10 Log[E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   3/10 Log[E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/10 Log[E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))] + 
   1/10 Log[E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j)/(
     2 E^(-(h/Sqrt[3])) + 2 E^(h/Sqrt[3]) + 
      E^(-(h/Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[2] j) + E^(h/Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[2] j) + 
      E^(-Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j) + E^(Sqrt[3] h + Sqrt[2] j))];
ContourPlot @@ {o, {j, -1, 1}, {h, -1, 1}}
FindMaximum @@ {o, {{j, -0.008983550852535105`}, {h, 
    0.06931364191023386`}}, Method -> "Newton"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically, I'm not sure exactly why Netwon's method fails, but the examples in the [documentation for `FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindMaximum.html#ExampleSection) point out this specific problem and error message under **Possible Issues**: "*With machine-precision arithmetic, even functions with smooth maxima may seem bumpy*".

Thus, if you increase the working precision with e.g. the `WorkingPrecision -> 20` option to `FindMaximum` the warnings go away:

```
In[25]:= FindMaximum[o, {{j, 0}, {h, 0}}, Method->"Newton", WorkingPrecision->20]

Out[25]= {-2.0694248079871222533, {j -> -0.14189560954670761863, h -> 0}}
```

Given that the text of the error is fairly descriptive:

> FindMaximum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance
>   specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient increase 
>   in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to 
>   meet these tolerances. >>

... I suspect Newton's method is failing to reached a fixed point with sufficiently small error using machine-precision arithmetic.

As the error message hints, you can instead use the `AccuracyGoal` option to specify the number of significant digits you want in the solution if you don't want to switch to slower high-precision arithmetic:

```
In[27]:= FindMaximum[o, {{j, 0}, {h, 0}}, Method -> "Newton", AccuracyGoal -> 5]

Out[27]= {-2.06942, {j -> -0.141896, h -> -2.78113*10^-17}}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, looks like AccuracyGoal->5 is what I needed to get rid of all my warnings