# EstimatingDistribution for StableDistribution

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, probability

I have 2 sets of data:

```
d1= {0.119894,0.430666,0.0831885,0.0319174,0.120422,0.113005,0.396407,0.286316,0.0846212,0.0380193,0.047136,0.0362305,0.0445161,0.142403,0.0540607,0.133119,0.10831,0.173586,0.162465,0.0704632,0.0856676,0.086322,0.31334,0.210488,0.165907,0.119317,0.0995894,0.103821,0.135736,0.245069,0.0814167,0.142331,0.321499,0.0576824,0.0535766,0.0546975,0.121395,0.0608112,0.0606295,0.133289,0.0468469,0.0501325,0.0641351,0.0846396,0.317252,0.0779754,0.105217,0.0749865,0.302625,0.301864,0.0929992,0.12178,0.279253,0.245539,0.198353,0.107202,0.17784,0.145572,0.055006,0.0770127,0.0861758,0.189966,0.21403,0.0834313,0.206845,0.2087,0.263422,0.0767717,0.162445,0.0542824,0.0553086,0.141381,0.052898,0.0945407,0.0776741,0.0367623,0.0565677,0.166219,0.035447,0.120121,0.0418321,0.11264,0.0540176,0.120358,0.074417,0.242225,0.398622,0.308373,0.15192,0.278717};

d2={0.170719,0.099203,0.0539713,0.15749,0.150455,0.142714,0.0705496,0.0690684,0.0630756,0.0372223,0.0885515,0.0305229,0.0869673,0.0426363,0.0504665,0.0371966,0.0766164,0.0402321,0.0334813,0.0489499,0.0753463,0.0942363,0.0786223,0.335095,0.0706324,0.0764047,0.0682716,0.0699429,0.0355438,0.0755698,0.10206,0.199187,0.0560379,0.0342713,0.0500202,0.0558365,0.0624332,0.0418887,0.0531662,0.0499419,0.0273659,0.0228881,0.0893776,0.0643183,0.0171277,0.0373337,0.0457631,0.0764322,0.0963383,0.0633643,0.107952,0.0570244,0.19336,0.0428824,0.0629954,0.120787,0.0924894,0.0562895,0.125588,0.116919,0.196895,0.264337,0.0787541,0.318374,0.193144,0.147134,0.0456675,0.0419496,0.057378,0.0577714,0.0706519,0.0410366,0.0716635,0.0547774,0.0157382,0.030444,0.0769898,0.0121786,0.0586156,0.0314843,0.0942514,0.1627,0.0781299,0.148406,0.423559,0.276206,0.0708934,0.0812794,0.159947};
```

Now I want to find an Estimated distribution using StableDistribution[]

For the first data set I do the following:

```
dist1 = EstimatedDistribution[d1, StableDistribution[alpha, beta, mu, sigma]]
```

I get a message and output

```
FindMaximum::sdprec: Line search unable to find a sufficient increase in the function value with MachinePrecision digit precision. >>

StableDistribution[1,0.863446,1.,-0.0781627,0.0345779]
```

The output looks ok (not a great fit for the data, but not too bad) but what does the message imply for the output?

For the second data set, d2

```
 dist2 = EstimatedDistribution[d2, StableDistribution[alpha, beta, mu, sigma]]
```

I get a different message.

```
Optimization`ModifiedCholeskyDecomposition::herm: The matrix {{2.76856*10^157,-1.75574*10^159,-1.84519*10^157,-2.26892*10^157},{7.88598*10^159,0.,6.41507*10^159,7.88598*10^159},{1.82386*10^157,6.41507*10^159,1.13495*10^157,1.82386*10^157},{-2.26892*10^157,-1.75574*10^159,-1.84519*10^157,1.68961*10^157}} is not Hermitian or real and symmetric.
```

and output:

```
StableDistribution[1,0.834688,1.,-0.0101189,0.0181306]
```

So, I've got a couple of questions.  Can anyone explain these messages and their relevance?  It looks to me that Mathematica tries a number of different ways to estimate the distribution and some just don't work very well.

Thx.

J.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make parameter estimation for stable distribution efficient, a multivariate interpolation of the pdf(alpha, beta, x) is constructed, and the resulting interpolation is used for estimation. Polynomial interpolation exhibits small scale oscillations, which can throw off the maximization routines. Thus, in working with stable estimation, it is better to use PrecisionGoal->3, AccuracyGoal->3.

Doing this does not get rid of your messages, though, but will speed-up estimation, which matters for larger size problems.

Since you data-size is small, statistical uncertainties of the estimators are large anyway.

The first message is benign, but the second is probably a bug, since the log-likelihood 
of the estimated distribution on data is too low.

As an aside, it seems that StableDistribution is not a very good fit for your data:

```
In[44]:= LogLikelihood[
  EstimatedDistribution[d1, StableDistribution[a, b, c, d]], 
  d1] // Quiet

Out[44]= 101.926

In[45]:= LogLikelihood[
  EstimatedDistribution[d1, HyperbolicDistribution[a, b, c, d]], 
  d1] // Quiet

Out[45]= 111.847

In[46]:= LogLikelihood[
  EstimatedDistribution[d2, StableDistribution[a, b, c, d]], 
  d2] // Quiet

Out[46]= -10.2194

In[47]:= LogLikelihood[
  EstimatedDistribution[d2, HyperbolicDistribution[a, b, c, d]], 
  d2] // Quiet

Out[47]= 143.04
```

Answer (score 2):

A general comment about numerical optimizer warnings -- I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570799/why-does-findmaximum-with-newtons-method-complain-it-cant-find-a-sufficient-dec) with using `FindMaximum` and getting "sufficient decrease" warnings, even though output seemed fine. It had to do with the fact that default `AccuracyGoal` of 6 could not be guaranteed, but smaller goal could be met without warnings.

You can globally turn the warning off with `Off[FindMaximum::sdprec]` or suppress it on per-command basis with

```
Quiet[EstimatedDistribution[d1,StableDistribution[alpha, beta, mu, sigma]], FindMaximum::sdprec]
```

Comment: I found Quiet[] and then edited my original post before I saw your reply.  Thx